# Querying xml returns null when using Linq to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml in a file:

```
<Person>
    <Name first="John" last="Doe" />
</Person>
```

I loaded the xml document with XDocument.Load, but I can't seem to get the values of the first and last attribute.

I tried:

```
var q = from n in rq.Element("Name")
        select n;  //but q is null after this.
```

Comment: Does it even compile? The Element Method returns an XElement, which is not enumerable (or queryable), so that LINQ expression should fail to compile. I guess you mean the Elements Method (plural).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that should work with your XML file:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(...);

var query = from node in doc.Root.Elements("Name")
            select new           //      ↑
            {
                First = (string)node.Attribute("first"),
                Last  = (string)node.Attribute("last")
            };

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{1}, {0}", item.First, item.Last);
}
```

Comment: I think it was compiling, but I was doing doc.Element instead of doc.Root.Elements.

Comment: How can I get the value for the first and last attributes from query?  I tried query.Select(x=>x.first), but that doesn't work.